# Linux software RAID: Does it work if device nodes change?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

If, for some reason, hard disks change device identifiers (e.g. /dev/sda becomes /dev/sdb and vice versa) does this affect a Linux software RAID system? I.e. would the device still work (assuming boot and root are not on that RAID partition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAID array itself doesn't care about the device nodes, because each component device stores its own metadata, including the UUID of the array that it belongs to.  When you assemble the array, if you specify the UUID instead of the device node paths — for example, if you have `UUID=` on its line in `mdadm.conf` — then it should continue to work even if the device nodes change.

Comment: OK, thanks! I can safely keep twiddling with the server then.